# iOS 5.0 Check if NSString contains Emoji characters

Tags: ios5, nsstring, emoji

I have an iOS 5 application that allows users to enter username with international keyboards.
I want to check if the input (NSString *) contains an emoji character or not.

Disabling emoji keyboard is not an option (Using UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable as it disables some of the international keyboards).

I tried  [this](https://gist.github.com/2946536). But it does not detect some of the characters like [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY2Im.jpg).

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to detect all emojis in iOS 5 and iOS 6 emoji keyboards using following method
https://gist.github.com/4146056

Comment: This is not correct. This solution will not work with unicode characters that Apple interprets as emojis but were actually around before the emoji characters were created and indexed in unicode. For example the 5th emoji character on the emoji keyboard (which has been around forever in unicode, before Apple changed it to an emoji) --> ☺ <-- that one is rendered as an emoji on an iPhone

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/woxtu/NSString-RemoveEmoji Category, but note that
iOS 9.1 added more emojis that above mentioned method doesnt recognize (especially these ones:).

FIX: replace
`return (0x1d000 <= codepoint && codepoint <= 0x1f77f);` in `isEmoji` method with
`return (0x1d000 <= codepoint && codepoint <= 0x1f77f) || (0x1F900 <= codepoint && codepoint <=0x1f9ff);`

Comment: This still allows for certain characters such as ☺️, add the following: (0x2100 <= codepoint && codepoint <= 0x26ff)

Answer (score 0):

To iOS 10 and below, you should check if the unicode if between the following values.

```
if ((0x1d000 <= uc && uc <= 0x1f77f) || (0x1f900 <= 0x1f9ff)) {
     //is emoji
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSData *data = [yourstringofemo dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


if ([goodValue rangeOfString:@"\u"].location == NSNotFound) 
{
      goodvalue string contains emoji characters
} 
else
{
      goodvalue string does not contain emoji characters
}
```

Comment: This filters out non emoji characters like "ı".